# Wordpress - get user list of following users

Tags: php, wordpress, list, author

I'm using the plugin "[user following system](https://pippinsplugins.com/series/creating-a-user-follow-system-plugin/)" and all I need to get is a list of users which I follow. I tried it with the snippet below but it always returns an array!
What am I doing wrong?

```html
function pwuf_get_following( $user_id = 0 ) {

 if ( empty( $user_id ) ) {
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
 }

 $following = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_pwuf_following', true );

 if ( empty( $following ) ) {

 return;

 }
 return (array) apply_filters( 'pwuf_get_following', $following, $user_id );

ob_start(); ?> 
<ul>
    <?php
 $following = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_pwuf_following', true );
 foreach( $following as $user ) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $user->first_name; ?> <?php echo $user->last_name; ?></li>
   <?php } ?>
</ul>
 <?php

  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'following', 'pwuf_get_following' );
```

Comment: Hello brother can you help me @Florian

Comment: Any help please @GhazanfarMir